# Анонимные классы

Tags: java

Объясните пожалуйста,что такое Анонимные классы,желательно на примере,а то не могу понять их принцип работы.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo {
    Foo(String param) {};
    public static void main(String... s) {
        new Foo(s[0]){};
    }
}
```

Где Foo является анонимным с невозможностью описания конструктора, т.е. локальный класс без имени.